# Disable caching in send_file

Tags: caching, flask, http-headers

Is there a way to prevent flask from setting caching headers in `send_file` or do I have to manipulate them manually afterwards?

Answer (score 25):

`send_file` accepts `cache_timeout` parameter - just set it to 0

With Flask 2.0, you can even use it in the `send_from_directory` function e.g.

`send_from_directory('server/assets', 'path', cache_timeout= 0)`

and it will hand it down to `send_file`

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory