# How to create then download a file flask

Tags: python, flask

When I click the button to download the file it seems to work the first time and then downloads the same even when the db has been updated. It doesn't seem to go through the exports def after the first time. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Here's my code for the button and for the route:

```html
<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ url_for('exports') }}" role="button">Export CSV</a>
```

```py
@app.route('/exports', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def exports():
    outfile = open('exports/export.csv', 'w')
    outcsv = csv.writer(outfile)
    records = db.session.query(Choice).all()
    [outcsv.writerow([getattr(curr, column.name) for column in Choice.__mapper__.columns]) for curr in records]
    outfile.close()
    return send_file('exports/export.csv', as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: just a wild guess, but maybe your browser is caching the output?

Comment: send_file takes a cache_timeout parameter that I wasn't setting. Thanks!

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557539/disable-caching-in-send-file